# How to write to a single table via Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, arcpy, parallel-processing

A comment in the post [Can multiprocessing with arcpy be run in a script tool?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140533/can-multiprocessing-with-arcpy-be-run-in-a-script-tool) got me thinking, as I often need to do exactly this:

> Just beware of deadlocking situations (two Insert cursors in the same
>   table for instance)

My question is, *how can you write to a single table when using multiprocessing*?

Here's an example script, which iterates through the sample City layer, and uses multiprocessing to copy each city's values to an output table via an insertCursor (this simplifies the more complicated scenario I have in mind).

```
# Testing how to write to an output fGDB table via multiple threads
import os, sys, arcpy, multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def Worker(input, output):
    for func in iter(input.get, 'STOP'):
        inputs = func
        doProcess(inputs)

def doProcess(inputs):
    outTblName = inputs[0]
    city = inputs[1]
    pop = inputs[2]
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchGDB, outTblName), ["NAME", "POPULATION"]) as iCursor:
        try:
            iCursor.insertRow([city, pop])
        except:
            print("Problem inserting " + city + " : " + str(pop) + " : trying again" )
            doProcess(inputs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES = 8
    task_queue = Queue()
    done_queue = Queue()

    inFC = "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\TemplateData\TemplateData.gdb\World\City"
    outTblName = "testTable"

    #Create the empty table
    outTable = os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchGDB, outTblName)
    if(arcpy.Exists(outTable)):
       arcpy.Delete_management(outTable)
    arcpy.CreateTable_management(arcpy.env.scratchGDB, outTblName)
    arcpy.AddField_management(outTable, "Name", "TEXT")
    arcpy.AddField_management(outTable, "Population", "DOUBLE")

    #Iterate through the cities. Send each one to the multiprocessor
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inFC, ["NAME", "POPULATION"]) as sCursor:
        for city in sCursor:
            cityName = city[0]
            pop = city[1]
            task_queue.put([outTblName, cityName, pop])

    for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES):
        Process(target=Worker, args=(task_queue, done_queue)).start()

    for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES):
        task_queue.put('STOP')
```

As expected it runs into problems when multiple threads try to access the output table simultaneously. Even when calling the `doProcess` function again recursively after errors are detected, the output table contains fewer rows than the input table.

An idea is for each thread to create a new table, and to append them all at the end. Are there any best-practise suggestions?

Comment: MultiUser is up to the underlying database or feature type. SDE would/should/might have no problems with this scenario but I would expect fGDB, pGDB and Shapefile to have problems with multiple insert cursors declared on the same table... it should be possible to write to different (copies) of the same table and merge at the end after all threads are complete, that's worked for me before. +1 for trying!

Comment: I also tried calling the function recursively in the case of errors - still no dice. I guess creating multiple tables and appending them is the best workaround

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson how can I detect when the whole process is finished, so I can append the tables? If I include `print("finished")` indented by one tab (same level as the `with arcpy.da.SearchCursor...`) this is the first (not last) thing I see.

Comment: I'm not sure, I usually use subprocess which returns an object that has a .communicate method, then wait until all are finished. If the task is dependent on speed I would use C#/C++ which is already faster than python and multiprocess with their objects; it is only when I want to use geoprocessing and multiprocessing, for example I did contours using different Z offsets and then merged, worked great! using os.environ.set with TEMP and TMP to keep them separate.

Comment: Posting as a comment as I haven't tested... @Stephen, if you _really_ want to write to a single table from multiple processes, have a look at the [multiprocessing.Lock()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes) object. You'll likely still have to deal with ArcGIS locking as well though. It might be easier to implement a [multiprocessing.Queue()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) and have the insertcursor running in the main process and child processes passing rows back to the main process.

Comment: @Luke thanks, `multiprocessing.Lock()` works. But it seems to remove any benefits of multiprocessing as it creates a bottleneck. I guess the whole approach is flawed, as per Michael's original comment which started this whole exploration!

Comment: @Stephen whether it removes any benefit really depends on what processing you are doing. There is no benefit with this example regardless of the locking given the pool initialisation overhead. I do think the main use case for multiprocessing is farming out CPU intensive tasks and collating results in the main process. Trying to manage shared access to non-multiuser resources like a GDB is fraught...

Answer (score 2):

Never tried multiprocessing, decided to give it a go.
This script:

```
import os, sys, arcpy, multiprocessing
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteoutput=1
scratchGDB=r'd:\rubbish\TEST.gdb'

def function(inputs):
    print ("got arg %s" % inputs)
    outTblName = inputs[0]
    city = inputs[1]
    pop = inputs[2]
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(os.path.join(scratchGDB, outTblName), ["NAME", "POPULATION"]) as iCursor:
        try:
            iCursor.insertRow([city, pop])
        except:
            print("Problem inserting " + city + " : " + str(pop) + " : trying again" )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    number_of_cpus = 5
    outTblName = "testTable"
    outTable = os.path.join(scratchGDB, outTblName)
    if(arcpy.Exists(outTable)):
       arcpy.Delete_management(outTable)
    arcpy.CreateTable_management(scratchGDB, outTblName)
    arcpy.AddField_management(outTable, "Name", "TEXT")
    arcpy.AddField_management(outTable, "Population", "DOUBLE")

    bList=[]
    for i in range (number_of_cpus):
        bList.append([outTblName,chr(65+i),i*i])
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(number_of_cpus)
    for i in pool.map(function, bList):
        print("Writing")
    rows=arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(os.path.join(scratchGDB, outTblName),["NAME", "POPULATION"])
    print (rows)
```

Gave me this output:
[image]

It works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the tips - not bad for your first multiprocessing script :) I think the problem only occurs when multiple processes try to access the insertCursor simultaneously, which doesn't happen in your simple script. If I replace your `bList` with the larger list generated by loading all the cities (`for city in sCursor: bList.append([outTblName, city[0], city[1]])`, I get the same result as my original script. That is, only around 450 of the original 593 cities are added.