ArcPy function produced None values in multiprocessing
I'm trying to get my script in multiprocessing, but the arcpy.management.CalculateGeometryAttributes produced None values. I tried it in for loop and it worked perfectly fine.
import os
import datetime
import arcpy 
import multiprocessing
import sys

def process(fc):
        arcpy.env.workspace = "G:/usgrids2020/test1/"
        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
        state = fc[34:-7]
        print(f"Processing for {state.upper()}")
        readTime = datetime.datetime.now()
        # arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(gdb_path, f"usa{state}.gdb")
        #Import the feature for boundary and water
        # fc = f"usa{state[3:5]}_joined"
        fcInMem = arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(fc, f"in_memory/usa{state}_fcInMem")
        water_fc = f"{fc[:-7]}_water_layer"
        waterInMem = arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(water_fc, f"in_memory/usa{state}_waterInMem")
        #Create the temporary id for joining fields later
        arcpy.AddField_management(fcInMem,'tempid','LONG')
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(fcInMem,"tempid",'!OBJECTID!','PYTHON')
        #Calculate the area(land+water) by GEODESIC method => Kytt recommended
        arcpy.management.AddField(fcInMem, "GEODESIC_AREA", "FLOAT")
        arcpy.management.CalculateGeometryAttributes(fcInMem, "GEODESIC_AREA AREA_GEODESIC", "", "SQUARE_METERS")        
        print("Starting intersect fishnet to boundary...")
        fish_net = f"G:/usgrids2020/fishnets/usa{state}_fishnet.gdb/usa{state}_fishnet"
        fishnetInMem = arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(fish_net, f"in_memory/{state}_fishnetInMem")
        intersectOut = f"in_memory/{state}intersect_fc"


    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fcInMem, ["GEODESIC_AREA", "GEOID20"]) as cursor:
        for i in range(10):
            for row in cursor:
                print(row)
                break
    print("Summarizing...")
    print(f"Finished processing for {state.upper()} in {str(datetime.datetime.now() - readTime)}")




def main():
    arcpy.env.workspace = "G:/usgrids2020/test1/"
    gdbs = arcpy.ListWorkspaces("*", "FILEGDB")
    procList = [os.path.join(gdb,f"{os.path.basename(gdb)[:-4]}_joined") for gdb in gdbs]
    multiprocessing.set_executable(os.path.join(get_install_path(), 'python.exe'))
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2,maxtasksperchild=1)
    results = pool.map(process, procList)
    
    for result in results:
        print(result)

    # Synchronize the main process with the job processes to
    # ensure proper cleanup.
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

def get_install_path():
    ''' Return 64bit python install path from registry (if installed and registered),
        otherwise fall back to current 32bit process install path.

        Copied from https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/140777/2856
    '''
    if sys.maxsize > 2**32: return sys.exec_prefix #We're running in a 64bit process

    #We're 32 bit so see if there's a 64bit install
    path = r'SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7'

    from winreg import OpenKey, QueryValue
    from winreg import HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, KEY_READ, KEY_WOW64_64KEY

    try:
        with OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, path, 0, KEY_READ | KEY_WOW64_64KEY) as key:
            return QueryValue(key, "InstallPath").strip(os.sep) #We have a 64bit install, so return that.
    except: return sys.exec_prefix #No 64bit, so return 32bit path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

The sample above produced this
(None, 'USA_100030117003015')
(None, 'USA_100030127001011')
(None, 'USA_100030151002006')
(None, 'USA_100030121001003')
(None, 'USA_100030112051009')
(None, 'USA_100030148102015')
(None, 'USA_100030112062022')
(None, 'USA_100030168063009')
(None, 'USA_100030166141010')
(None, 'USA_100030164041013')

And the expected output should be
(20561.794921875, 'USA_110010105004003')
(30113.7734375, 'USA_110010079014005')
(12254.59765625, 'USA_110010022022000')
(35741.94921875, 'USA_110010105004002')
(4266.21240234375, 'USA_110010070002021')
(3911.968994140625, 'USA_110010055021003')
(4928.87890625, 'USA_110010031001004')
(17638.513671875, 'USA_110010104002006')
(120078.6015625, 'USA_110010009042003')
(47717.84375, 'USA_110010105003001')
(27098.328125, 'USA_110010105004008')
(14594.705078125, 'USA_110010032004000')
(34655.69140625, 'USA_110010025042001')


StackExchange content is is CC-BY-SA licensed. So when you copy code from here, you are required to attribute it - https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing

I might be wrong but think the problem is that you are using a single location for each process to write to, the in_memory workspace. Try for each process writing to a separate unique dataset? Have a look at my code here.

@Hornbydd it's confused because the other functions from arcpy worked fine such as AddField and CalculateField, but when it came to CalculateGeometryAttributes the function generated None values

Looks to be a defect with CalculateGeometryAttributes.  I was able to create a minimum reproducible example and have submitted to Esri Support to log a defect.  Will update when I know more.

Thanks for the updates. Hopefully it is a defect with the function.
